# Alter column, add default constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, alter-table, alter-column

I have  a table and one of the columns is "Date" of type datetime. We decided to add a default constraint to that column

```
Alter table TableName
alter column dbo.TableName.Date default getutcdate()
```

but this gives me error:

> Incorrect syntax near '.'

Does anyone see anything obviously wrong here, which I am missing (other than having a better name for the column)

Comment: Don't use types or keywords as column names!

Comment: yup, agreed-"Does anyone see anything obviously wrong here, which I am missing (other than having a better name for the column)"

Answer (score 387, accepted):

Try this

```
alter table TableName 
 add constraint df_ConstraintNAme 
 default getutcdate() for [Date]
```

example

```
create table bla (id int)

alter table bla add constraint dt_bla default 1 for id



insert bla default values

select * from bla
```

also make sure you name the default constraint..it will be a pain in the neck to drop it later because it will have one of those crazy system generated names...see also [How To Name Default Constraints And How To Drop Default Constraint Without A Name In SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/how-to-name-default-constraints-and-how-)

Comment: what does the insert bla default values do?  I would think setting the constraint would set the defaults for you.

Answer (score 7):

you can wrap reserved words in square brackets to avoid these kinds of errors:

```
dbo.TableName.[Date]
```

Comment: It seems like a really bad idea to use reserved words for column names.

Comment: It seems, but it's not. I use them successfully since 2004 :)

Answer (score 7):

Actually you have to Do Like below Example, which will help  to Solve the Issue...

```
drop table ABC_table

create table ABC_table
(
    names varchar(20),
    age int
)

ALTER TABLE ABC_table
ADD CONSTRAINT MyConstraintName
DEFAULT 'This is not NULL' FOR names

insert into ABC(age) values(10)

select * from ABC
```

Comment: This just use for practice, cannot use in reality

Answer (score 7):

I use the stored procedure below to update the defaults on a column.

It automatically removes any prior defaults on the column, before adding the new default.

Examples of usage:

```
-- Update default to be a date.
exec [dbo].[AlterDefaultForColumn] '[dbo].[TableName]','Column','getdate()';
-- Update default to be a number.
exec [dbo].[AlterDefaultForColumn] '[dbo].[TableName]','Column,'6';
-- Update default to be a string. Note extra quotes, as this is not a function.
exec [dbo].[AlterDefaultForColumn] '[dbo].[TableName]','Column','''MyString''';
```

Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- Sample function calls:
--exec [dbo].[AlterDefaultForColumn] '[dbo].[TableName]','ColumnName','getdate()';
--exec [dbol].[AlterDefaultForColumn] '[dbo].[TableName]','Column,'6';
--exec [dbo].[AlterDefaultForColumn] '[dbo].[TableName]','Column','''MyString''';
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[ColumnDefaultUpdate]
    (
        -- Table name, including schema, e.g. '[dbo].[TableName]'
        @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100), 
        -- Column name, e.g. 'ColumnName'.
        @COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(100),
        -- New default, e.g. '''MyDefault''' or 'getdate()'
        -- Note that if you want to set it to a string constant, the contents
        -- must be surrounded by extra quotes, e.g. '''MyConstant''' not 'MyConstant'
        @NEW_DEFAULT VARCHAR(100)
    )
AS 
BEGIN       
    -- Trim angle brackets so things work even if they are included.
    set @COLUMN_NAME = REPLACE(@COLUMN_NAME, '[', '')
    set @COLUMN_NAME = REPLACE(@COLUMN_NAME, ']', '')

    print 'Table name: ' + @TABLE_NAME;
    print 'Column name: ' + @COLUMN_NAME;
    DECLARE @ObjectName NVARCHAR(100)
    SELECT @ObjectName = OBJECT_NAME([default_object_id]) FROM SYS.COLUMNS
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@TABLE_NAME) AND [name] = @COLUMN_NAME;

    IF @ObjectName <> '' 
    begin
        print 'Removed default: ' + @ObjectName;
        --print('ALTER TABLE ' + @TABLE_NAME + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @ObjectName)
        EXEC('ALTER TABLE ' + @TABLE_NAME + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @ObjectName)
    end

    EXEC('ALTER TABLE ' + @TABLE_NAME + ' ADD  DEFAULT (' + @NEW_DEFAULT + ') FOR ' + @COLUMN_NAME)
    --print('ALTER TABLE ' + @TABLE_NAME + ' ADD  DEFAULT (' + @NEW_DEFAULT + ') FOR ' + @COLUMN_NAME)
    print 'Added default of: ' + @NEW_DEFAULT;
END
```

**Errors this stored procedure eliminates**

If you attempt to add a default to a column when one already exists, you will get the following error (something you will never see if using this stored proc):

```
-- Using the stored procedure eliminates this error:
Msg 1781, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

Answer (score 2):

I confirm like the comment from JohnH, never use column types in the your object names!
It's confusing. And use brackets if possible.

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName]
ADD  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [Date];
```

Comment: Better still, use `"double quotes"`, as that is the ANSI standard.

Answer (score 1):

alter table TableName
 drop constraint DF_TableName_WhenEntered

alter table TableName
 add constraint DF_TableName_WhenEntered
 default getutcdate() for WhenEntered

Comment: this answer contains the drop constraint query too.if someone had added getdate() earlier and now he needs to alter it to getutcdate(). he might get some help through this answer. @RalfFriedl

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying the table name twice. The ALTER TABLE part names the table.
Try:
Alter table TableName
alter column [Date] default getutcdate()