# MS SQL Server Import - Importing Data With New NON NULL Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, import

I am trying to import from an old database into an updated one.

The databases are basically identical except in one of my tables I added a new column that is NOT NULL.

This obviously makes errors when I used the importer to move the rows over.  Is there a way that I can define a default for this new NOT NULL field when doing an Import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add a default constraint to the new column.  See this post: [Alter column, add default constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095289/sql-server-alter-column-adding-default-constraint)

> alter table TableName
>   add constraint df_ConstraintNAme
>   default > getutcdate() for [Date]

Comment: Surely that will raise an error message like `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near '>'.` If you remove the `>` character, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Two options are:

1) Define a DEFAULT value constraint on the column

2) Temporarily make the column NULL, do the import, then reapply the NOT NULL constraint