# Adding an automatic date field to MYSQL database using stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

i have a table called entry .

Table have 2 column called `id & name` .

When user filled the name and submit name is saved in entry table .

Now i want to save the date also . But this date need to filled automatically in database . That is when name is filled the current timezone of my selected country should be saved automatically in the table .

I already created the date column in table . Now how can i do this ? Is there any stored procedure will help this ?

I cant write any query in my php file . It should done in mysql side .

Please help

Comment: you can use default constraint to populate date. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095289/alter-column-add-default-constraint

Answer (score 1):

You may use `trigger` for same. Use `after insert` so whenever you add a record it will automatically update date.

I am not a regular `mysql` user, so syntax might be different but you'll get the idea for same. Please find the link for more info. [TRIGGER](https://www.siteground.com/kb/mysql-triggers-use/).

```
CREATE TRIGGER inserttable 
AFTER INSERT 
ON table1 
FOR EACH ROW 
   NEW.DATECOL = (SELECT CURDATE());
END
```

Feel free to edit this code if any syntax issue is there.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the creation date/time can be handled through the table definition using a default value:

```
create table t (
    . . . , 
    created_at timestamp default current_timestamp
);
```

This is much simpler than defining a trigger for this purpose.

Note that this stores the date and time value.  I don't think MySQL lets you store only the time.  But because you mention timezones, this may be what you really want.

Comment: but the table is already created before and there are some entries in table . For the previous entry the date will be like 00.00.000 like that . So please check . I need to store only date , even if time is zero